# Apply Button on Filter with cssSelector or xPath Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have this part in the source:

```
<div class="CFApplyButtonContainer" style="height: 21px;">
   <button class="tab-button tab-widget disabled" style="max-width: 67px;" disabled="" type="button">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="label">Cancel</span>
   </button>
   <button class="tab-button tab-widget disabled" style="max-width: 67px;" disabled="" type="button">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="label">Apply</span>
   </button>
</div>
```

And my Java part is like this:

```
// detect type of the filter 

if (type.equals("")) {
            elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + id + "_menu']//a[@class='FIText']"));
        if (elementList.size() > 0) {
            if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + id + "_menu']//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']//span[@class='label'][text()='Apply']/..")).size() > 0) {
                type = "multi_checkbox_with_apply";
            }
            else {
                type = "multi_checkbox_without_apply";
            }
        }
    }

 //if apply button enabled
             element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='"+id+"_menu']//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']//span[@class='label'][text()='Apply']/..")));
            if (element.getAttribute("disabled") == null) {
            element.click();
            //log("clicked on apply button");
            waitForLoadingSpinner();
        }
        else {
            //log("apply button disabled - no need to click on it");
        }

        // close drop down menu
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='tab-glass clear-glass tab-widget']")));
        element.click();
        //log("dropdown menu closed");
    }
```

Is this correct way to find the span that contains "Apply"? My apply suddenly stop working and don't know what else to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can search for text inside a tag (other than looking for link text that only applies to `A` tags) is to use an XPath. The below should get what you want.

```
//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']/button/span[text()='Apply']
```

To use this as you did in your question

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']/button/span[text()='Apply']")).size() > 0)
{
    // found the element, do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks on help but when I put this: if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='CFApplyButtonContainer']/button/span[text()='Apply']")).size() > 0) it just stops, nothing is doing, somehow with this size()>0 don't wanna click on apply button. I don't know what to do

Comment: The if statement I provided above doesn't do a click so I'm assuming you are clicking elsewhere? Given the HTML you provided, this XPath works. If you add stuff to it, as you've shown in your question, I can't help you there without more info.

Comment: Hello, your solution is working, just I have problem with filtering in one point and don't know how to skip that part. But thanks a lot !